# Text Adventure Game, adding time and game ending

Tags: java

I am making a simple text adventure game, but I got 2 little problems..

Problem 1: I want to make an end game goal.. which is once the player reached a certain room, the game ends.. but i cannot seem to get the if statement correct..

Problem 2: I want to make a time limit(steps) lets say a user will get 30 steps to complete the game.. so for every room he enters, the counter will get +1.. and once he reaches 30 steps he will loose.

I have a createRooms method that creates rooms and their locations

```
private void createRooms()
{
    Room gate, graveyard, church, crypt, entrance, hall, kitchen, buttery, greathall, staircase,
        dungeon, topstaircase, throne, solar, wardrobe, privy;

    // create the rooms
    gate = new Room("outside the old gate of the castle");
    graveyard = new Room("on a wind-swept gaveyard");
    church = new Room("in a small ancient church with medieval windows");
    crypt = new Room("in the crypt of the church");
    entrance = new Room("at the big wooden entrance of the castle");
    hall = new Room("in the dark entrance hall of the castle");
    kitchen = new Room("in the kitchen with a huge table and a big stove");
    buttery = new Room("in the buttery of the castle");
    greathall = new Room("in the great hall of the castle with its magnificient huge windows");
    staircase = new Room("at the staircase");
    dungeon = new Room("in the dark dungeon of the castle");
    topstaircase = new Room("at the top of the staircase");
    throne = new Room("in the throne room with golden walls");
    solar = new Room("in the solar of the castle");
    wardrobe = new Room("in the wardroble of the Lord of the castle");
    privy = new Room("in the privy");

    // initialise room exits

    gate.setExit("north", graveyard);

    graveyard.setExit("south", gate);
    graveyard.setExit("east", church);
    graveyard.setExit("north", entrance);

    church.setExit("west", graveyard);
    church.setExit("south", crypt);

    crypt.setExit("north", church);

    entrance.setExit("south", graveyard);
    entrance.setExit("north", hall);

    hall.setExit("south", graveyard);
    hall.setExit("west", kitchen);
    hall.setExit("north", greathall);
    hall.setExit("east", staircase);

    kitchen.setExit("east", hall);
    kitchen.setExit("south", buttery);

    buttery.setExit("north", kitchen);

    greathall.setExit("south", hall);

    staircase.setExit("west", hall);
    staircase.setExit("down", dungeon);
    staircase.setExit("up", topstaircase);

    topstaircase.setExit("down", staircase);
    topstaircase.setExit("north", throne);
    topstaircase.setExit("south", solar);

    throne.setExit("south", topstaircase);

    solar.setExit("north", topstaircase);
    solar.setExit("west", wardrobe);
    solar.setExit("east", privy);

    wardrobe.setExit("east", solar);

    privy.setExit("west", solar);

    currentRoom = gate;  // start game at gate
}
```

This is what i tried

```
if(room == throne) {
    System.out.println("Congratulations you have won the game!");
    System.out.println("Press any key then enter to continue")
    System.exit(); 
}
```

Im also not sure how to how to make it pause after the Congratulations message, and make a user press any key then enter, before closing the game.

As for the times.. Dont exactly know where to begin.. I presume I need to write something like:

```
For(Every goRoom)
int a +1
When(int a ==30)
System.out.println("You have Lost the game")
then the game exits or starts the game..
```

would that be correct?

Comment: try `equals` instead of `==` in your if statement `room.equals(throne)`

Comment: Suggest you x-post to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It gives me error that it cannot find symbol throne

Comment: for your actual issue, checkout scanner: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html and use it on System.in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full answer for your problems, as it seems you have some problems to make your program run: do that first, then you can decide what you do for victory and user interactions.

Your `Room` variables are defined only within the scope of the `createRooms` method, which seem wrong. You need to define them globally in your class (try moving the line

```
Room gate, graveyard, church, crypt, entrance, hall, kitchen, buttery, greathall, staircase, dungeon, topstaircase, throne, solar, wardrobe, privy;
```

outside the method (and make them `private`, it's always good to make variables private unless you need to access them from outside: it preserves encapsulation.)

Also if you want to count the user steps, you need a variable to hold that count, in your class.

```
private Room gate, graveyard, church, crypt, entrance, hall, kitchen, buttery, greathall, staircase, dungeon, topstaircase, throne, solar, wardrobe, privy = null;
private int steps = 0

private void createRooms() {
  gate = new Room("outside the old gate of the castle");
  graveyard = new Room("on a wind-swept gaveyard");
  ...
```

Then you can call from any of your class method:

```
if (room.equals(throne)) {
  // any of your victory printout
```

That will at least put you on the right path.

I would also suggest you don't put your `System.out.println` statement directly in your main class, you should separate the concerns of game mechanics (your main class) and user interface, using a pluggable interface (dependency injection).

For example you can define something like `interface UserOutput`, with methods on it like `onVictory`, `onRoomChange`, etc. and you implement it with a `class ConsoleUserOutput` which does `System.out.println`statements in all these methods. And you inject that `ConsoleUserOutput`in your main class at creation time (so that the main class only knows about the interface `UserOutput`). Even better, you can plug all the user interactions this way: waiting for him to press a key, etc.